# Automate pasting (Ctrl + v ) other than using pyautogui?

Tags: python, clipboard, paste

Is there a way other than using `pyautogui` to make Python **paste from clipboard (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>)** in a new or an existing .xlsx file?

The output from another application previously run is stored in the clipboard.

Everything works OK when I manually open the workbook and paste data, I just want to automate it.

Comment: You could do it _very_ indirectly by creating an [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script, compiling that into an `.exe.` executable, and then run it from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the string from the clipboard using [`pyperclip`](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/):

> The purpose of Pyperclip is to provide a cross-platform Python module for copying and pasting text to the clipboard.
>
> ...
> To paste the text from the clipboard, call `pyperclip.paste()` and the text will be returned as a string value.

```py
import pyperclip
pyperclip.paste()
```

Since it's now a string, you can then use any of the existing Python-based Excel libraries to put that string into your workbook (or any file I/O libraries if it's not specific to Excel files).

Here's an example using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (mostly based on the [Simple usage - Write a workbook example](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#write-a-workbook) from the `openpyxl` docs):

```py
import pyperclip
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Create a new workbook
wb = Workbook()
wb_filename = "example.xlsx"

# Create a new sheet
ws = wb.create_sheet(title="example")

# Paste the contents to this new sheet
# Here, let's just paste into cell A1
ws["A1"] = pyperclip.paste()

# Finally save the workbook
wb.save(filename=wb_filename)
```

Comment: @AkIonSight No, they are still **different** packages. This is pyperclip: https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/, last release 1.8.1 Oct 11 2020. This is clipboard: https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/, last release 0.0.4 May 22 **2014**. I just edited to fix the broken link to pyperclip readthedocs page. The code in this answer *still* works as I test it now. You have [your clipboard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057659/2745495), I have my pyperclip one. I am not going to recommend a 6yr old package. Even the clipboard package author said "*everything is included in pyperclip already*".

Answer (score 0):

(*This answer was copied from OP's [edit that added "SOLVED" into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59654728/4)*)

I have managed to solve this by using Get-Clipboard > filename.csv by using the Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

you can dump copied data to excel directly using **pandas**

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.read_clipboard() 

df.to_excel(output_xl, sheet_name ='your sheet_name', engine ='xlsxwriter', index=False)
```

Comment: Please improve your answer a bit to be better readable

Answer (score 0):

## **You can use the clipboard module**

#### Installing via pip

execute
`pip install clipboard`
in the terminal

### Usage

Easy usage

```py
import clipboard
clipboard.copy("abc")  # now the clipboard content will be string "abc"
text = clipboard.paste()  # text will have the content of clipboard
```

Comment: Do take note that the [clipboard](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/) package has not been updated **since 2014** and if you look at [its source code](https://github.com/terryyin/clipboard), it is doing nothing but installing, importing, and using pyperclip :) See [clipboard.py](https://github.com/terryyin/clipboard/blob/master/clipboard.py) and its [setup.py](https://github.com/terryyin/clipboard/blob/master/setup.py)